# Testing Java Endpoints on real device in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform

I followed this tutorial to setup a cloud database for my Android App

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints

Everything compiled fine and the server is running at http://localhost:8080/

However I keep getting this error

failed to connect to /10.0.0.2(port 8080) after 20000ms

I tried replacing 10.0.0.2 with my local IP address but it didn't work and showed the same error.

I am using Android Studio and debugging the app on my Android phone. Kindly help. Thanks!

Comment: have you actually deployed the App engine project?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of areas to check:

1. Make sure you can connect to your locally running server using local IP address. In in your computer browser go to :8080. If it doesn't work then make sure your Run/Debug Config in AS is calling  127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0 address.
2. your android app has to be calling your pc's local IP address.

Comment: Yes I can connect to my local server and I am calling my PC's local IP address.

Comment: Can you connect to it from your Phone's browser?

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the dev server listening on 0.0.0.0. By default, the dev server listens only on localhost which means requests from other devices will not work. Just edit your run configuration and set the server address.

Answer (score 0):

1. First find the IP Address of your machine (e.g., 192.168.x.x), by using ifconfig.
2. Change your build.gradle file of the endpoints project by adding this code `appengine.run.host='192.168.x.x'` at the end of the file.
3. Change the address in your android code with `.setRootUrl("http://192.168.x.x:8080/_ah/api")`